# Format a number in a Textbox on Enter key press

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, textbox, formatting

In a windows Form, I have a text box  where I put amounts, for example I would type 18369.25 then press Enter key, the textbox should be formatted to: 18 369,25
how to do that ?

Comment: have you looked at string.Format function.

Comment: Yes: var s = String.format(format, args); I need to know how to get the format above and which event to use for the Enter Key.

Comment: var value = textbox.Text;
String.Format({0:## ###,##}, value); try something like this.. also google string.formatting

Comment: What about when user enters 1234567.89 ?

Comment: 1234567.89 should become:   **1 234 567,89**

Comment: String.Format({0:##,###.##}, value) should be a . sorry typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the textbox's KeyPress event with an event handler similar to the one below:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        decimal value;
        if (decimal.TryParse(
            textBox1.Text,
            NumberStyles.Any,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out value))
        {
            textBox1.Text = value.ToString(
                "### ### ##0.00",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TrimStart().Replace(".", ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for integer values: 123456789 become 1 234 567,89 that's good, but when I type 123456.25 it doesn't change.

Comment: Can I also ask why this format (18 369,25)?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: Yes I use only your code. for info I have a french keyboard and my OS is french also. My regioanl settings are: Default

Comment: This is a french format, Dan. We use space for thousands and "," for decimals.

Comment: Well the reason why it didn't work is probably because of our machines having different culture settings.  I've made an edit that should fix it.  Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did some expiriments, but none seemed to work. So I came out with this solution. I know its not the best one, but at least it work (for at least what you required):

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)        
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            if (s.Contains('.'))
            {
                string[] arr = s.Split('.');
                decimal dec = decimal.Parse(arr[0]);
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0},{1}", dec.ToString("## ###"), arr[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you have any other requirements, please let me know.
bye

Comment: This is working when I type decimal values and not when I type integers, Thank you Mitja.